# to get foreach values in other foeach loop php

Tags: php

Here I have given my code.

```
            $std_details   = $this->db->query('CALL table("'.$field1.'"')->result_array();
            $form_list = array();
            foreach($std_details as $details)
            {
                $id =$details['id'];
                $list =  $this->db->query('CALL table("'.$field1.'","'.$field2.'","'.$field3.'","'.$field4.'","'.$field5.'", "'.$field6.'")')->result_array();

                array_push($form_list, $list);
            foreach($list as  $datalist1)
            {
                foreach ($datalist1 as $datalist)
                {
                $subdata = array();
                $subdata[] = $datalist['field_name1'];
                $subdata[] = $datalist['field_name2'];
                $action = '<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons"> 
                            <a class="blue" href="'.base_url().'folder/controller/functionname/'.$details['id'].'" title="Preview" ><i class="fa fa-eye bigger-130" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
                              </div>';
                $subdata[] = $action;
                $data['data'][$Count] = $subdata;
                $Count++;
             }
             } 
             }
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
```

Here I have to get the $details['id'] from $std_details and i have to pass these id in below shown foreach loop in $action variable. Now i am getting only the last value of array for every row ie, $details['id'].Since I am new to coding,  Pls help me to resolve the issue and point out the error.

Comment: Read your code first, foreach ($datalist as $datalist) ? Use proper variable names;

Comment: By mistake given same variable now changed. Thats not the issue, getting the last result values of metioned id in every row

Comment: Why it looks complicated